# Creating own component and selector causes errors

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my angular2 app. I have that code:

```
// app.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello</h1><my-courses></my-courses>`,
    directives: [CoursesComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular2';
}
```

and

```
// courses.component.ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-courses',
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})
export class CoursesComponent {

}
```

And my app doesn't work. After I deleted `<my-courses></my-courses>` from template in app.component.ts it started working, but without my courses component.
After i add this back, it will cause that errors:
[image]

What I do wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the components part of the same `module`? 
If so, I guess that you aren't importing / declaring the `component` in your `module`.

Do this:

```
import { CoursesComponent } from './your-path';
// ... other imports    

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      CoursesComponent
      ...
  ],
  // ...

export class AppModule { ... }
```

Also, you don't need to import `CoursesComponent` in `AppComponent`, just in `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your ngModule:

```
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
```

import `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` from `@angular/core`

This is because you have a `-` in your component selector.